# Saving image to Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, alamofireimage

I want to parse these small avatar images to core data, I  have this function using AlamofireImage.

However, on the setting of the result to the core data property, I get this error.

> Cannot assign value of type 'Data?' to type 'NSData?'

Here is my code:

```
self.managedObjectContext = self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext
let contactAvatar = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
contact.avatar = contactAvatar
do {
    try self.managedObjectContext?.save()
} catch {
    fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
}
```

My Core data entry is Binary Data. I thought I should be able to save to this format correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

- Declare the attribute `avatar` as `Data` in the model (preferable)
- Bridge cast `contactAvatar as NSData`

Comment: you cant declare Data as a type in the model? Just binary data

Comment: `Data` is the Swift 3 equivalent of `NSData`

Comment: im saving you cant have either as an attribute in the core data entity, NSData and Data dont exist as options fpr saving to

Comment: `(NS)Data` == binary data

Comment: From my previous experience, saving/loading Data from CoreData is very time-consuming. Instead of doing that, you can just save the image as a file in one of you app's folder, then store the link to that file, it would be more efficient.